# Matching all columns with all search phrases

Tags: c#, sql, plsql

I want to let a user search through all the columns in a table for a set of phrases defined in a textbox (split terms with whitespace).
So what first came to mind is finding a way in SQL to concatenate all the columns and just use the LIKE operator (for each phrase) in this result.
The other solution I thought of is writing an algorithm which takes all the phrases searched, and match them with all the columns.
So I ended up with the following:

```
String [] columns = {"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"};
String [] phrases = textBox.Text.Split(' ');
```

I then took all the possible combinations of columns and phrases, and put that into a where-clause-format for sql and then the result was

```
"(col1 LIKE '%prase1%' AND col1 LIKE '%phrase2%') OR
(col1 LIKE '%phrase1%' AND col2 LIKE '%phrase2%') OR
(col1 LIKE '%phrase2%' AND col2 LIKE '%phrase1%') OR
(col2 LIKE '%phrase1%' AND col3 LIKE '%phrase2%')"
```

The above is just an example snippet of the output, the amount of conditions being created in this algorith is measured by

```
conditions=columns^(phrases+1)
```

So I observed that having 2 search phrases can still give good performance, but more than that will certainly decrease performance drastically.

**What is the best practise when searching all the columns for the same data?**

Comment: How large a table are you going to be searching? are all columns character fields? and do you need to worry about case sensitivity?

Comment: There are only about 500 rows in the table. All the columns are text except for a "price" column. We made a web crawler and limited it to one domain to retrieve data about all the products. I don't worry about case sensitivity.

Comment: You should look for [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Comment: @VahidND That is a good suggestion, but I am working with Oracle (sorry for not mentioning) and it seems like the CONTAINS operator works with a weighting factor, which returns all the results containing at least one of the phrases. But I guess I can use a LIKE on the index which needs to be created instead.

Comment: VahidND - in his example he requires both suffix and prefix searching which ins't supported in Full-Text (at least without a hack of putting in reverse text) and it is probably overkill for 500 rows. I would probably create a view with all the fields combined and then call a stored proc that uses a temp table to do the matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edwin,

I didn't know you was using ORACLE. My solution is using SQL Server. Hopefully you will get the gist of the solution and translate into PL/SQL.

Hopefully this is useful to you.

I am manually populating the #search temp table. You will need to somehow do that. Or look for some Split Function that will take the delimited string and return a Table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#keywords') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #keywords;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#search') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #search;

DECLARE @search_count INT

-- Populate # search with all my search strings
SELECT *
INTO #search
FROM (
    SELECT '%ST%' AS Search

    UNION ALL

    SELECT '%CL%'
    ) T1

SELECT @search_count = COUNT(*)
FROM #search;

PRINT @search_count

-- Populate my #keywords table with all column values from my table with table id and values
-- I just did a select id, value union with all fields
SELECT *
INTO #keywords
FROM (
    SELECT client_id AS id
        ,First_name AS keyword
    FROM [CLIENT]

    UNION

    SELECT client_id
        ,last_name
    FROM [CLIENT]
    ) AS T1

-- see what is in there 
SELECT *
FROM #search

SELECT *
FROM #keywords

-- I am doing a count(distinct #search.Search). This will get me a count, 
--so if I put in 3 search values my count should equal 3 and that tells me all search strings have been found
SELECT #keywords.id
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT #search.Search)
FROM #keywords
INNER JOIN #search ON #keywords.keyword LIKE #search.Search
GROUP BY #keywords.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT #search.Search) = @search_count

SELECT *
FROM [CLIENT]
WHERE [CLIENT].client_id IN (
        SELECT #keywords.id
        FROM #keywords
        INNER JOIN #search ON #keywords.keyword LIKE #search.Search
        GROUP BY #keywords.id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT #search.Search) = @search_count
        )
```

Comment: If I understand right, you basically create a temporary table with the words being searched and then use UNION between this temporary table and the table being searched. So whichever row was joined the amount of times of the number of keywords, should be a match. But what if a certain row has replicated data for example: 
col1(url): "http://domain/phones/samsung/s5"
col2(product_title): "samsung s5"
Will a certain keywords be joined with the same column twice?
Every keyword may only occur(counted) once in a row.

Comment: @Edwin, so if i have the 2 columns above as you say and my search strings are 'samsung' and 'galaxy', should that row be return in the results? and also, if i have the 2 columns as you stated above, and my search string was 'samsung' should this row be returned?

Comment: If we take the 2 columns above with the data "domain/phones/samsung/s5" and "samsung s5" and then search for "samsung" and "galaxy", the row should not be returned because "galaxy" wasn't in any column. But if you only searched "samsung", the row must be returned. @Ed Mendez

Comment: @edwin, that is what it will do. in my solution. I insert all words being searched into #search temp table. I then use the Union to add all the column values & primary key Id of the table that needs to be search into #keywords temptable. then I do a group by and join the two tables based on LIKE and return only the Ids where the distinct count of search terms is equal to the count of search terms. So if I have am searching for samsung & galaxy, I will return the Ids only if the samsung and galaxy if found in any columns.

Comment: I missed the GROUP BY. It will indeed work then. And to answer my own question, I think it will be better (regarding performance) to use this method with a UNION of the key words table.
So if I have conditions=columns^(keywords+1);
And you have a UNION=columns*keywords;
Obviously your solution has less operations.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stored procedure or function in PL/SQL to dynamically search the table for the search terms and then bring back the primary key and column of any matches. The code sample below should be enough to tailor to your requirements.

```
create table text_table(
    col1  varchar2(32),
    col2  varchar2(32),
    col3  varchar2(32),
    col4  varchar2(32),
    col5  varchar2(32),
    pk    varchar2(32)
);

insert into text_table(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, pk)
values ('the','quick','brown','fox','jumped', '1');
insert into text_table(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, pk)
values ('over','the','lazy','dog','!', '2');

commit;

declare 

  rc                  sys_refcursor;
  cursor_num          number;  
  col_count           number;
  desc_tab            dbms_sql.desc_tab;  
  vs_column_value     varchar2(4000);  
  search_terms        dbms_sql.varchar2a;
  matching_cols       dbms_sql.varchar2a;
  empty               dbms_sql.varchar2a;
  key_value           varchar2(32);

begin

  --words to search for (i.e. from the text box)
  search_terms(1) := 'fox';
  search_terms(2) := 'box';

  open rc for select * from text_table;

  --Get the cursor number
  cursor_num := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(rc);

  --Get the column definitions
  dbms_sql.describe_columns(cursor_num, col_count, desc_tab);

  --You must define the columns first
  for i in 1..col_count loop
    dbms_sql.define_column(cursor_num, i, vs_column_value, 4000);    
  end loop;

  --loop through the rows    
  while ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(cursor_num) > 0 ) loop 

    matching_cols := empty;

    for i in 1 .. col_count loop --loop across the cols

        --Get the column value
        dbms_sql.column_value(cursor_num, i, vs_column_value);

        --Get the value of the primary key based on the column name
        if (desc_tab(i).col_name = 'PK') then 
            key_value := vs_column_value;
        end if;

        --Scan the search terms array for a match
        for j in 1..search_terms.count loop
           if (search_terms(j) like '%'||vs_column_value||'%') then
               matching_cols(nvl(matching_cols.last,0) + 1) := desc_tab(i).col_name;
           end if;
        end loop;    
    end loop; 

    --Print the result matches
    if matching_cols.last is not null then
        for i in 1..matching_cols.last loop
            dbms_output.put_line('Primary Key: '|| key_value||'. Matching Column: '||matching_cols(i));
        end loop;
    end if;

  end loop;

end;
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but the problem is where you loop through the columns to see if it matches one of the search terms - It will immediatly add it to the matching columns result, even if there is only one match. **I require each of the search terms to occur at least once** in the specified row. And even adding a counter variable to say X number of matches was found in a row can be faulty due to the possibility of redundency (as in my comment on the answer of Ed Mendez)